# If a user keeps rolling back my appropiate edits, what can I do?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

So, I'm attempting to edit a question on SO, which has unnecessary tags. The question OP is being a grumpy bear and disagrees with the edit, so he/she keeps rolling it back. In a situation like this, what should be done?

Comment: The relevant question is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10602418/http-referer-and-user-agent-origin

Comment: I locked it, since the edits seem to be happening and ongoing *in real time* (last updated *a few seconds ago*!). It'll unlock in a bit once the user has cooled off...

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn You might want to leave a comment to point the OP to this post. We can't since you just locked it.

Comment: @Mysticial: Good point. I've posted a comment now. I think I'll wait till later to lock it again if he insists on rolling back.

Comment: Forget the tags, the relevant question should be closed as NARQ.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker Or off topic - either way it is now. Thank goodness.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- Comment, and tell him why you think they are unnecessary
- If he doesn't listen, flag the post for ♦ and dump what you wrote here in the textarea. Or, you can come to meta, like you did.

Edit wars get temporarily locked.

Answer (score 5):

The following excerpt by Jeff Atwood:

> ... And as mentioned in the [blog entry on edit wars](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/the-great-edit-wars/), if there’s any
> resistance — even unwarranted and unjustifiable resistance — just let
> go and move on.

[(source)](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/in-defense-of-editing/)

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, that question really didn't need edited in the first place. It was clearly off-topic and had nothing to do with programming. It doesn't matter what tags it uses because *none* of them would be relevant. Questions like that you should really just leave be and let them be quietly deleted so they go away. Don't worry about what tags they have.